# Is it possible to Navigate back in Salesforce1 to previous page after save processing?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

Is there a way I can go back to previous calling page after processing save on a Visualforce Page in Salesforce1?

I have a Page where I click on a link and I use navigateURL() function to process this navigation, now in this VF page, I have a form that requires some input values and a button Save.

I want to be able to go back to the previous calling page after I complete the Save processing. How can I do that?

Comment: Any one knows how to do back navigation from Salesforce1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in one the comments of the link below:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000009K2LIAU

Code: `sforce.one.back(true);`

Comment: yes, I found it earlier, but thnx for adding it here as answer as well, gonna mark it now.